# FileGDB In GDAL Docker container with dot net core

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr, file-geodatabase, docker

Currently, I am using this docker image pepperlk/gdal that has FileGDB built in and working via command line.

Details here:

```
gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.3.0beta1-b75f14ab12155c6b6f4544a9894c41f2f9a7d241, released 2021/04/20

ogrinfo --formats
<concat for clarity>
  OpenFileGDB -vector- (rov): ESRI FileGDB
  FileGDB -vector- (rw+): ESRI FileGDB
```

To reproduce...
Running within the container:

```
MaxRev.Gdal.Core.GdalBase.ConfigureAll();
var drcount = OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.GetDriverCount();
for (int i = 0; i < drcount; i++)
{
    var driver = OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.GetDriver(i);
    Console.WriteLine($"Driver Name: {driver.name}");
}
```

Yields:

```
Driver Name: ESRIC
Driver Name: PDS4
Driver Name: VICAR
Driver Name: PDF
Driver Name: MBTiles
Driver Name: BAG
Driver Name: EEDA
Driver Name: OGCAPI
Driver Name: ESRI Shapefile
Driver Name: MapInfo File
Driver Name: UK .NTF
Driver Name: LVBAG
Driver Name: OGR_SDTS
Driver Name: S57
Driver Name: DGN
Driver Name: OGR_VRT
Driver Name: REC
Driver Name: Memory
Driver Name: BNA
Driver Name: CSV
Driver Name: NAS
Driver Name: GML
Driver Name: GPX
Driver Name: KML
Driver Name: GeoJSON
Driver Name: GeoJSONSeq
Driver Name: ESRIJSON
Driver Name: TopoJSON
Driver Name: Interlis 1
Driver Name: Interlis 2
Driver Name: OGR_GMT
Driver Name: GPKG
Driver Name: SQLite
Driver Name: WAsP
Driver Name: PostgreSQL
Driver Name: OpenFileGDB
Driver Name: XPlane
Driver Name: DXF
Driver Name: CAD
Driver Name: FlatGeobuf
Driver Name: Geoconcept
Driver Name: GeoRSS
Driver Name: GPSTrackMaker
Driver Name: VFK
Driver Name: PGDUMP
Driver Name: OSM
Driver Name: GPSBabel
Driver Name: SUA
Driver Name: OpenAir
Driver Name: OGR_PDS
Driver Name: WFS
Driver Name: OAPIF
Driver Name: HTF
Driver Name: AeronavFAA
Driver Name: EDIGEO
Driver Name: SVG
Driver Name: CouchDB
Driver Name: Cloudant
Driver Name: Idrisi
Driver Name: ARCGEN
Driver Name: SEGUKOOA
Driver Name: SEGY
Driver Name: ODS
Driver Name: XLSX
Driver Name: Elasticsearch
Driver Name: Carto
Driver Name: AmigoCloud
Driver Name: SXF
Driver Name: Selafin
Driver Name: JML
Driver Name: PLSCENES
Driver Name: CSW
Driver Name: VDV
Driver Name: GMLAS
Driver Name: MVT
Driver Name: NGW
Driver Name: MapML
Driver Name: TIGER
Driver Name: AVCBin
Driver Name: AVCE00
Driver Name: HTTP
```

In .net I am missing that installed driver what am I missing??
`ogr2ogr` is working fine as well as `ogrinfo` via command line but not available in code.